# Apollo GraphQl renderToStringWithData always same data after server run

Tags: reactjs, express, graphql, apollo

I just created an expressJs server for SSR with apollo Graphql.
I have this issue: After the page is started the source of the page is what expected, but until the server is running, that data fetched by Graphql is never changing.

this is what I have in the source of the page:
[image: html source code]

Im currently using http://fake.graphql.guru/graphql to get some mock data, and there data change to every request randomly.

Following the code of expressjs and the apolloClient config

```
// express js
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  renderToStringWithData(<StaticRouter location={req.url} context={{}}><App /></StaticRouter>).then((content) => {
  const initialState = client.extract();
  res.status(200);
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
  res.send(Template({
    content,
    state: initialState,
  }));
  next();
  });
});

// apollo client
const client = new ApolloClient({
  ssrMode: true,
  link: new HttpLink({
    fetch,
    uri: 'http://fake.graphql.guru/graphql',
  }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'PROD' ? 
    window.__APOLLO_STATE__ : null),
  defaultFetchPolicy: 'network-only',
  ssrForceFetchDelay: 100,
});
```

So what im expecting on every request is the server returning a new html page with new data. What is wrong?

Comment: here the github code if some one want to take a look https://github.com/kenta88/graphqlMockApp/tree/server_side_rendering

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for that:
in order to reset the client's cache for every request is just enough to call **client.resetStore()**

```
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
// reset the client cache
client.resetStore();
renderToStringWithData(<StaticRouter location={req.url} context={{}}>
<ReactApp /></StaticRouter>).then((content) => { // eslint-disable-line
  const initialState = client.extract();
  res.status(200);
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
  res.send(Template({
    content,
    state: initialState,
  }));
  next();
  });
});
```